# How show menu item in Material Table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I tried the material table and wanted to add a menu item in the action, so that it doesn't display too many actions like edit, delete. I have a problem displaying the menu item.

Example code:

```
<MaterialTable
  columns={[
   { title: t('customer'), field: 'name' },
   { title: t('email'), field: 'email' },
   { title: t('contactNumber'), field: 'contactNumber' },
   { title: t('status'), field: 'status' },
  ]}
  data={list}
  options={{
   headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#00b7b2',
    },
    toolbar: false,
   }}
   actions={[
    {
      icon: 'menu',
      tooltip: 'Menu',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
       this.openMenu(event)
         },
       },
      ]}
      components={{
       Action: props => (
        <div>
         <IconButton
           onClick={(event) => props.action.onClick(event, props.data)}
         >
          <Icon>menu</Icon>
         </IconButton>
           <Menu
             anchorEl={this.anchorEl}
             open={Boolean(this.anchorEl)}
             onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()}
             onSelect={event => event.stopPropagation()}
             onClose={this.closeMenu}
           >
             <MenuItem>
                 Action
              </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
         </div>
        ),
      }}
    />
```

Is there is a solution for me?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I successfully accomplished this. Basically you are on the right track.

Have an action as you said above:

```
  <MaterialTable
      ...
            actions={[
                {
                  icon: MenuIcon,
                  tooltip: 'Actions',
                  isFreeAction: false,
                  onClick: (event, row) => {
                    this.openMenu(event, row);
                  }
                }
             ]}
     ...
  />
```

but then have a separate Menu item in render:

```
      <Menu
         id="simple-menu"
         keepMounted
         anchorEl={this.state.menuAnchor}
         open={this.state.menuOpen}
         onClose={this.handleMenuClose}
         >
         <MenuItem onClick={this.doSomething}>do something</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem onClick={this.doSomethingElse}>do something else</MenuItem>
       </Menu>
      </center>
```

Trick is openMenu() should first get the current target:

```
openMenu(event, row) {
    let anchorElement = event.currentTarget;
    this.setState({currentRow: row}, () => {
      this.setState({menuAnchor: anchorElement});
      this.setState({menuOpen: true});
    });

  }
```

```
doSomething() {
   row = this.state.currentRow;

   // do something
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!